# Translating Annotations with FME

Tags: fme-form, annotation, dgn, file-geodatabase-api

There is a situation where I have annotation in dgn file as an attribute info, eg: it is circumference of trees trunk. I have a feature class in esri file geodatabase named ‘tree’ which has an attribute ‘tree circumference’. Is it possible to copy these annotation values  into the appropriate field of attribute table of feature class (point). Below is the picture of annotation layer and tree layer in dgn file. Here the ellipses and arcs are already converted into esri point feature class. Now the annotations associated with them are to be copied in attribute table. Is this possible with FME ? How ?

[image]

Result of match from NeighborFilter (max dist  = 5)

[image]

**Possible solution is :**

Use Sorter with 'min'. Next, to separate the first item(ie: minimum distance value) from the rest use DuplicateRemover. Since we dont need any values other than the nearest, use AttributeCreator to change them to blank.

[image]

Comment: I can see you also have Arcmap running, how about doing a Spatial join there? By just converting your dgn to shape you'll get the annotations into a point file, that you can join to your "real" features. You might have to try a few different search distances if your data is complex, though.

Comment: How about using a neighborfinder or a spatialfilter transformer?

Comment: Yes, Martin there is a possibility to do it in arcmap. but i am kind of trying to learn to do things with FME. If not possible i will definitely consider your guideline.

Comment: Hi Fezter, i have already converted the ellipses into point . So  now i am actually trying to match points in annotations and point features. I have put one picture above. NeighbourFilter is good in that it matches but it does not match one to one due different proximities. With max distance set to 5 it matches 73 and with 2 it matches 27. Where as there are 51 real annotation in the dgn file which needs to be matched.

Comment: Set the max distance high and include a list attribute. That will give you a list of the nearest annotations with a distance to them. Pick the one that is closest (ListSorter, ListIndexer). That should help - but the NeighborFinder is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Hi Mark, I am afraid, I did not understand the concept of ListSorter and Listindexer - how they can be used to extract the minimum distanced annotation value. If you can give some detail it will be useful . I have explained above  (under LIST ATTRIBUTE) what i have done and understood.